# Classic ASP sql server "operation is not allowed" error

Tags: jquery, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm getting error:

```
Request object error 'ASP 0104 : 80004005'

Operation not Allowed

/post.asp, line 3
```

This error came after attempting to write to my database. The code I added was

```
    jquery stuff{
    ar2 = useless2.split("Summary");
    ar = ar2[0];
    re = new RegExp("\n", "g");
    useless = ar.replace(re, "<br>");
    re = new RegExp('"', "g");
    useless = ar.replace(re, '""');
    used = useless;
    }

html stuff{
<input type="hidden" name="vDescription_' + c + '" value="' + used + '">
}
```

(Yes I know used=useless is useless)

An example of what a description looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="vDescription_323" value=" 

0:07 Discussion

1:06 Introduction and Motivation

2:24 Support Vector Machines

6:59 The Financial Kernel (FK)

8:28 Kernel Methods

10:10 Example

10:14 Data Selection

10:34 Preprocessing

10:57 Testing

">
```

This is pulled from inspecting the elements. I'm not entirely sure why it shows me new lines instead of the 
 code, which may be contributing to the error?

ASP code:

```
<!--#include file="connv.inc"-->
<%
n=Request.form("total")
response.write(n)

for x = 0 to n-1
ttitle=Request.form("title_"&x)
title=Replace(ttitle, "'", "''")
id=Request.form("id_"&x)
views=Request.form("vViews_"&x)
likes=Request.form("vLikes_"&x)
description=Request.form("vDescription_"&x)

sql="if NOT exists (select * from tbl_videos where videoId = '"&id&"') INSERT INTO tbl_videos(videoTitle, videoId, videoLikes, videoViews, videoDescription, swamCompatible) values ('"&title&"', '"&id&"', '"&likes&"', '"&views&"', '"&description&"', '0')"
connv.execute(sql)
response.write(sql&"<br>")
next
%>

<html>
<head>
<title> Updating Tables </title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<!--#include file="closeEmv.inc"-->
```

Comment: You need to show the server side code in post.asp

Comment: @AlexK. oh forgot. its been added in.

Comment: I suspect line 3 relates to connv.inc

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities; if I submitted `"',0); delete from tbl_videos--"` in `vDescription`  I could do some damage.  Use a Paramaterized command instead.

Comment: @AlexK. Do I still need to protect from sql injection if the data is pulled directly from youtube api, not user input? Could it still be connv.inc if the error only comes up after I submit the description hidden form? I''m also sending many more variables in the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this error when the posted data size exceeds the ASP "Maximum Entity Requesting Body Limit".

From [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/327659):

> This issue occurs if a Content-Length header is present and if the Content-Length header specifies an amount of data that is larger than the value of the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed property in the IIS metabase. The default value for the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed property is 204,800 bytes.

Comment: Thats one of the errors I found, but I dont think any of the descriptions I'm passing has 100-200 thousand characters.

Comment: It looks like you're posting more than one description at a time. It is the total size that would be important. Is it possible that the total size exceeds the request size limit?

Comment: oh yea that is very possible. theres about 1000+ descriptions. so would I have to just update my server database a few hundred at a time?

Comment: @JonathanLin Yes, that's probably the best solution. You could increase the response limit, of course, but I'd avoid that if possible.